# Angular Material custom colors

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I would like to have access to more than 3 colors for my material theme.
For example, I would like to add in $theme-success: mat-pallete($mat-green) to have a green success color in my Material components like `md-checkbox color="success"`.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-yellow, A400, A200, A600);
$theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$theme: mat-light-theme($theme-primary, $theme-accent, $theme-warn);

.body-light {
  @include angular-material-theme($theme);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

The `color` bindings only support primary, accent, and warn.

If the coloring is simple (for checkbox, it's just `.mat-checkbox-background` and `.mat-ripple-element`), you can use the palette yourself:

```
$theme-success: mat-palette($mat-green);

.mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
  background-color: mat-color($theme-success, 0.26);
}
```

You could probably also get away with making 2 themes, where the second one uses your success color for `primary`

```
$theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-yellow, A400, A200, A600);
$theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$theme: mat-light-theme($theme-primary, $theme-accent, $theme-warn);

$theme-success: mat-palette($mat-green);
$theme2: mat-light-theme($theme-success, $theme-accent, $theme-warn);

.body-light {
  @include angular-material-theme($theme);
}

.component-success {
  @include angular-material-theme($theme2);
}
```

Comment: I found this very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you really need an extra color you can create class in styles.scss (or.css) or anywhere in your style sheets.

```
.mat-buttonSuccess{
    background-color: #ffff00;
    color: #000;
}
```

and then call it as color same way as primary, accent and warn.

```
<button mat-raised-button color="buttonSuccess">Success</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to make full use of the button features

1. I created a palette on my main theme file, _theme.scss

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$my-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-deep-purple);
$my-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);
$my-app-green:  mat-palette($mat-green);  // <------ My new palette

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$my-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$my-app-theme: mat-light-theme($my-app-primary, $my-app-accent, $my-app-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($my-app-theme);

@import './buttons';
```

2. I defined my override in _buttons.scss

```css
.mat-raised-button {
  &.mat-green {
    color: mat-color($my-app-green, darker-contrast);
    background-color: mat-color($my-app-green, default);
    
    &[disabled] {
      color: mat-color($mat-light-theme-foreground, disabled-button);
      background-color: mat-color($mat-light-theme-background, disabled-button);
    }

    .mat-ripple-element {
      @include _mat-button-ripple-background($my-app-green, darker-contrast, $_mat-button-ripple-opacity);
    }
  }
}
```

Everything I needed to figure these out are in `\node_modules\@angular\material\_theming.scss`

And a starting point from [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme)

Answer (score 1):

With angular 15 in 2023 you can use next mixin for applying `color="success"` and `color="info"`:

mat-button-variants.scss

```
@use 'sass:map';
@use 'sass:meta';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$_ripple-opacity: 0.1;

// Applies a focus style to an mat-button element for each of the supported palettes.
@mixin _focus-overlay-color($config-or-theme, $variants) {
  $config: mat.get-color-config($config-or-theme);
  @each $variant, $variant-palette in $variants {
    &.mat-#{$variant} .mat-button-focus-overlay {
      background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($variant-palette);
    }
  }
}

@mixin _ripple-background($palette, $hue, $opacity) {
  $background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($palette, $hue, $opacity);
  background-color: $background-color;
  @if (meta.type-of($background-color) != color) {
    opacity: $opacity;
  }
}

@mixin _ripple-color($theme, $hue, $opacity, $variants) {
  @each $variant, $variant-palette in $variants {
    &.mat-#{$variant} .mat-ripple-element {
      @include _ripple-background($variant-palette, $hue, $opacity);
    }
  }
}

// Applies a property to an mat-button element for each of the supported palettes.
@mixin _theme-property($theme, $property, $hue, $variants) {
  $background: map.get($theme, background);
  $foreground: map.get($theme, foreground);

  @each $variant, $variant-palette in $variants {
    &.mat-#{$variant} {
      #{$property}: mat.get-color-from-palette($variant-palette, $hue);
    }

    &.mat-#{$variant} {
      &.mat-button-disabled {
        $palette: if($property == 'color', $foreground, $background);
        #{$property}: mat.get-color-from-palette($palette, disabled-button);
      }
    }
  }
}

@mixin color($config-or-theme, $variants) {
  $config: mat.get-color-config($config-or-theme);
  $foreground: map.get($config, foreground);
  $background: map.get($config, background);

  .mdc-button:not(:disabled),
  .mat-mdc-icon-button:not(:disabled),
  .mat-mdc-stroked-button:not(:disabled) {
    @include _theme-property($config, 'color', text, $variants);
    @include _focus-overlay-color($config, $variants);
  }

  .mat-mdc-flat-button:not(:disabled),
  .mat-mdc-raised-button:not(:disabled),
  .mat-mdc-unelevated-button:not(:disabled),
  .mat-mdc-fab:not(:disabled),
  .mat-mdc-mini-fab:not(:disabled) {
    @include _theme-property($config, 'color', default-contrast, $variants);
    @include _theme-property($config, 'background-color', default, $variants);
    @include _ripple-color($config, default-contrast, $_ripple-opacity, $variants);
  }
}
```

you should define a scss map object with palettes for success and info:

material-theme-index.scss:

```
@use './mat-button-variants' as button-variants;

...

$theme-success: mat.define-palette($palette-success);
$theme-info: mat.define-palette($palette-info);

$variants-theme: (
  success: $theme-success,
  info: $theme-info,
);
// and include mixin above
@include button-variants.color($main-theme, $variants-theme);
```

and now it will work as should in
`<button mat-raised-button color="success">Click me</button>`

PS: if you use material lower versions like 14 and below please rename `mdc` to `mat` in classes due to latest breaking changes in material v15 with extra classes prefixes `mdc`. Current example works for angular 15+.

Comment: And where do the actual colors of info and success get set?

Comment: in the _palette.scss file. You need to define a palette for each "color", and next import it to the index file above. that's it.  https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: Fantastic solution @IgorKurkov!! Really thanks! The only thing is in Angular 16, the ripple doesn't take the right color, but is only gray. Anyway really amazing! I imagine this is really difficult to apply to each Material Components ?

Comment: of course, it's a bit tricky, but you can just create a similar file for another component that requires it, like toggle or slider-toggle, and adapt similar code like button-variants.scss for it. generally typography and palette will work with most of the mat-components. 
ps: however, yeah, ripple/background/foreground need additional effort and customising:)