# Add custom color variables in angular material (2+)

Tags: angular, colors, angular-material

How to create "custom" own colors for [angular material](https://material.angular.io/)?

For example the bootstrap like colors like `success` (green), `warn` (yellow), `danger` (red), beside `primary` (blue), `accent` (pink).

In other words: Extend the color variablen of Angular Material (2+) for using it in html attributes:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="success">Success</button>
```

or create a white checkbox like:

```
<mat-checkbox color="white">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the guide for customizing angular material theme? [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Comment: Yes, but I've found nothing about that. Or overlooked it. Just found how to modify existing colors like "primary". I'm a newbie in sass and theming like that. That's different from css styles by html selectors. :D

Comment: Click the link I gave you (the 'here' keyword)

Comment: @JanSomersJanS91 where in the document are additional variables (e.g. 'danger') mentioned?  I cannot see that anywhere.  Answer by mohit below seems to satisfy the question but involves editing angular node_module files which seems like a difficult-to-maintain solution.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45144023/angular-material-design-how-to-add-custom-button-color/65489817#65489817) answer will help someone. It will give you type hinting as well

Answer (score 10):

You can`t do it. But if you like you can add "color="whatever" attribute to some element of material and this adds custom class for you.

Example:

```css
.whatever {
  background-color: light-blue;
}
```

```html
<button mat-button color="whatever"></button> // this button will have '.mat-whatever' class.
```

Answer (score 10):

To add a new color named `success`, make the following changes

Add the following styles in your main styles.css file

```css
.mat-success {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #28a745 !important;
}
.mat-success[disabled] {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) !important;
}
```

Specify the color name in your component

```html
 <button mat-raised-button color="success">
```

Answer (score 5):

Variables are defined in "_theming.scss" which is under "node_modules/@angular/material/".To define the custom variable we need to modify the following functions.

```
// Creates a container object for a light theme to be given to individual component theme mixins.
@function mat-light-theme($success, $primary, $accent, $warn: mat-palette($mat-red)) {
  @return (
    success:$success,
    primary: $primary,
    accent: $accent,
    warn: $warn,
    is-dark: false,
    foreground: $mat-light-theme-foreground,
    background: $mat-light-theme-background,
  );
}

// Creates a container object for a dark theme to be given to individual component theme mixins.
@function mat-dark-theme($success, $primary, $accent, $warn: mat-palette($mat-red)) {
  @return (
    success:$success,
    primary: $primary,
    accent: $accent,
    warn: $warn,
    is-dark: true,
    foreground: $mat-dark-theme-foreground,
    background: $mat-dark-theme-background,
  );
}
```

> Inside the same file, we can also apply the newly introduced variable
>   to the component as i applied it for buttons.

```
// Applies a focus style to an md-button element for each of the supported palettes.
@mixin _mat-button-focus-color($theme) {
  $success: map-get($theme, success);
  $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
  $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
  $warn: map-get($theme, warn);

  &.mat-success .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color: mat-color($success, 0.12);
  }
  &.mat-primary .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color: mat-color($primary, 0.12);
  }
  &.mat-accent .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color: mat-color($accent, 0.12);
  }

  &.mat-warn .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color: mat-color($warn, 0.12);
  }

  &[disabled] .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

@mixin _mat-button-ripple-color($theme, $hue, $opacity: 0.2) {
  $success: map-get($theme, success);
  $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
  $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
  $warn: map-get($theme, warn);

  &.mat-success .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: mat-color($success, $hue, $opacity);
  }
  &.mat-primary .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: mat-color($primary, $hue, $opacity);
  }
  &.mat-accent .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: mat-color($accent, $hue, $opacity);
  }

  &.mat-warn .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: mat-color($warn, $hue, $opacity);
  }
}

// Applies a property to an md-button element for each of the supported palettes.
@mixin _mat-button-theme-color($theme, $property, $color: 'default') {
  $success: map-get($theme, success);
  $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
  $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
  $warn: map-get($theme, warn);
  $background: map-get($theme, background);
  $foreground: map-get($theme, foreground);

  &.mat-success {
    #{$property}: mat-color($success, $color);
  }
    &.mat-primary {
    #{$property}: mat-color($primary, $color);
  }
  &.mat-accent {
    #{$property}: mat-color($accent, $color);
  }
  &.mat-warn {
    #{$property}: mat-color($warn, $color);
  }

  &.mat-success ,&.mat-primary, &.mat-accent, &.mat-warn, &[disabled] {
    &[disabled] {
      $palette: if($property == 'color', $foreground, $background);
      #{$property}: mat-color($palette, disabled-button);
    }
  }
}

@mixin mat-button-theme($theme) {
  $success: map-get($theme, success);
  $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
  $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
  $warn: map-get($theme, warn);
  $background: map-get($theme, background);
  $foreground: map-get($theme, foreground);

  .mat-button, .mat-icon-button {
    background: transparent;

    @include _mat-button-focus-color($theme);
    @include _mat-button-theme-color($theme, 'color');
  }
```

> And new custom variable can be added inside the "theme.scss" file

```
@import '~@angular/material/_theming';

@include mat-core();

$primary: mat-palette($mat-green);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$warn: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$success: mat-palette($mat-blue);
$theme: mat-light-theme($success,$primary, $accent,$warn);

@include angular-material-theme($theme);

.dark-theme {
  $dark-success: mat-palette($mat-light-blue);
  $dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-blue);
  $dark-accent: mat-palette($mat-green);

  $dark-theme: mat-dark-theme($dark-success, $dark-primary, $dark-accent);

  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}
```

> Now We can use new variable inside the html:

```
<button  md-button color="success">Primary</button>
```

> Following is the link for modified _theming.scss https://plnkr.co/edit/gMAEyVjb0F7MCC1x6OKe?p=templates

Note: We need to take care of "_theming.scss" file while upgrading the angular-material package.

Comment: Where is your custom color variablen beside primary, accent or warn? You only modify the colors of existing variables (primary, accent, warn). But is it possible to create a new color variable e.g. named '$success' and use it in html attr color="success"? I think it's not possible without changes to the material project. Because you have to explicitly pass only existing variables to the theme. mat-light-theme(primary, accent, warn).

Comment: @Dominik yes it is possible but need to modify the material project. updated my answer with the detail

Answer (score -2):

I add a new color in the corresponding palette inside the file **_theming.scss** in **PROJECT_NAME\node_modules\@angular\material_theming.scss** this work's for me and pass  succefully the **ng build --prod**

You have to respect the contrast ratio between the color and font, in my case the color is #590F46 and have good contrast with white fonts.

do this

1. Add the new color inside the corresppnding palette in my case $mat-pink (color palettes start arround the row 500 so better use find **ctrl+f** in your text editor and search the palette name)
2. In the next section named **contrast:** choose the font color ( $dark-primary-text or $light-primary-text), respect the material design guidelines pls.
3. Remember! the node_modules folder are not backup by github/bitbucket etc so you have to backup this file and replace it for the default file if you clone this project and use **npm install** or other reasons, less dangerouse my recomendiation is just add your custom palette seccion and dont mess with the other code

Examples
[Code example just palette mat-pink in _theming.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBFrQ.png)
and 
[My file with custom themes for angular material2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv9m9.png)
Sorry for my english i just want to help :)

Comment: Never change anything in node modules as it will simply get overwritten when you attempt to update anything npm related