# How to change angular material button background color on hover?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

I want to change the background color of angular mat button on hover.

html

```
<button  style="font-family: 'Nunito'" button mat-button color="primary">Button</button>
```

css:

```
button.mat-raised-button:hover {
    background-color: 'red';    
}
```

BUt it is not working and I dont know why?

Comment: use `background-color: red !important` .. i think it will help you..

Comment: You can check my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401579/3339907

Answer (score 2):

Add a class while hover the button `hover-class`

```
button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="hover-class">Primary</button>
```

then

```
.hover-class:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**[`Working Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xf75rm-twuv1h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-types-example.css)**

Answer (score -1):

Your `HMTL` and `CSS` are invalid check the snippet:

```css
button.mat-raised-button:hover {
    background-color: red;    
}
```

```html
<button  style="font-family: 'Nunito'" class="mat-raised-button" color="primary">Button</button>
```